# Dissappearing <div> tag in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, html, rendering

I have an ASP.Net page in which I have encapsulated several elements on the page in a  tag on my master page so that I can apply styling to everything in the div as a unit. This is working fine in several places, but sometimes the div is not rendered in the client-side HTML, so my styling never shows up.

I am not able to include the actual source code because of corporate policy. However, the code looks something like this:

```
<div id="SideBarArea" class="SideBarStyle" runat="server">
  <div id="Top">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder="TopPlaceHolder" runat="server"/>
  </div>
  <div id="Bottom">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder="BottomPlaceHolder" runat="server"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Top and Bottom divs appear in the rendered HTML, but the SideBarArea does not--or at least does not always.

In reality, I have several similar master pages that were created over the lifetime of the application. The pages are similar and all have Top and Bottom divs, but they have been given different names. These divs are located on the left-side of the screen and logically make a side-bar area; however, they have not, historically, been bound together, except graphically by their position on the screen.

I have a new requirement to enable or disable the side-bar area depending on application logic. To accomplish this, have gone into allo the master pages and wrapped the Top and Bottom divs in a new div named SideBarArea with the intent of enabling or disabling the wrapper div. For most of the master pages, this approach has worked well, but on one of them, the SideBarArea div is not rendered in the final markup, and the corresponding HtmlGenericControl is null in the code behind.

As I have been writing this, my partner added a display style to the div as follows:

```
<div id="SideBarArea" class="SideBarStyle" runat="server" style="display:block">
  <div id="Top">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder="TopPlaceHolder" runat="server"/>
  </div>
  <div id="Bottom">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder="BottomPlaceHolder" runat="server"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

This forced the div to be rendered in the HTML and to be non-null, so the question is moot at this point; however, I'd still like to understand why this change worked and whether it is the "right" way to solve the problem.

Comment: You'll need to show us some markup/code.

Comment: Please include some of your source code, this question is too vague to be actionable.

Comment: show us some piece of html that you have written either by pasting here or by creating a fiddle.

Comment: Your quotes on Top and Bottom divs id and runat are incomplete

Answer (score 0):

Missing characters are wont to corrupt HTML, so `runat="server` could turn out terrible, evidently.

Be sure to properly compose your markup, and pay attention to any errors or warnings your IDE gives you. Consider your code as if it were a compiled language, one that simply wouldn't compile, much less be available to execute, until everything is syntactically sound. In fact, if you're using Visual Studio then you can configure it - a recommendation I#ll make at any opportunity - to treat warnings as errors, and hence cause a failed build in these cases, forcing you to look at what is wrong.

In the meantime, complete your quotes:

```
runat="server"
```

And:

```
id="Top"
```

And:

```
id="Bottom"
```

Comment: This is not the real code; it 's just the example I created for the question. The real code is quoted correctly. I've updated the examples.